# Youtube API - not loading if the user in not in the tab (FireFox)

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, tabs, youtube

I´ve been messing around with the youtube API for a while now.
I´m currently making a website where users can create custom playlists from different sources (youtube, soundcloud,...).

After one video is finished it checks on the go to the url with the next video.

The problem is that when you are in another tab than the one where the video plays and the next video loads, the API won´t load.

The only way to avoid this is by opening the link in a own browser.
(I use firefox btw)

It works with Internet Explorer though!
For the html part: I use the standard Iframe code
API:

> ```
> <script>
> var player;
> function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
>     player = new YT.Player('player', {
>       height: '390',
>       width: '640',
>       videoId: '<?php echo $link; ?>',
>       events: {           
>       'onReady': onPlayerReady,           
>       'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> function onPlayerReady(event) {
>
> ```
>         event.target.playVideo();
>     }
> ```
>
> function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
>
> ```
>    console.log('State is:', >event.data);         
>    if(event.data === 0) {
>       
>   window.location="link";             
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: This is actually a feature in Firefox to prevent ads from displaying content (for example, a popup ad in the background) without your explicit consent (consent being... going to the tab).

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: It is a problem with onStateChange. Youtube API is not working correctly since Dec 6 and the event is never fired. It has been reported here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5655

Comment: No, it works with Internet Explorer. In Firefox though the whole API won´t load

Comment: onReady is not working correctly either, as you may read in the link attached in my previous comment.

Comment: but it works in internet explorer